# Install4j - embedding jar into generated launcher

Tags: install4j

I have 'generated launcher' which executes my java application - aplication is in jar package.
Is there any way how to include jar into generated EXE file(launcher)? Customer wants to have only exe file, not jar in installed folder. Is there any way how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do that with install4j. You can do it with exe4j, by using the "JAR in EXE" mode and add the generated executable to the distribution tree instead of using the generated launcher. This only works for Windows, though.